# Why are spark3 dynamic partitions slow to write to hive

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hive, bigdata, spark3

#### Question 1:

I have a table with a small amount of data, but there are a lot of dynamic partitions in the daily writes, the original `spark2` writes can be solved in only 2 minutes, but after upgrading to `spark3` it takes 10 minutes to write completely. I learned that `spark3` has added a stricter transaction mechanism when writing data to `hive`, is it related to this, and how should it be solved?

#### Question 2:

This is one of my tasks, the code is almost the same adjusted part of the log printing, respectively, using `spark2` (left) and `spark3` run (right), in the case of the same parameters, `spark3` each job running speed are significantly better than `spark3`, but the total running time `spark3` spent 1.2h, while `spark2` only spent 44 min. Why this phenomenon occurs? What is this extra time used for?[The top part is the eventTime forspark2 r, and the bottom part is for a spark3]
[image]
[image]
I have tried setting these parameters, but none of them worked very well:

- `spark.sql.hive.useDynamicPartitionWriter=false`
- `spark.hadoop.hive.txn.manager=org.apache.hadoop.hive.sql.lockmgr.NoTxnManager`

This is my first time asking a question on StackOverflow. If there is anything I did wrong, please point it out. I will correct it in time, thanks!

Comment: I found that before the data was written to hive.spark will link to hivematestore and gat table matedata.After this,The programme stopped as if it were down.This gap in time is used for this.What was done during this time and what needs to be done to avoid it

Comment: You can connect to the metastore databases and check what queries are running. This might help to debug.

Comment: I found out that spark3 is using hive metastore 2.3.7 while spark2 is using 1.2.1, why is there such a big gap between the two

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before writing to the Hive table Spark needs to read the metadata. It does so by connecting to the hive metastore and pulling the partition info. This is what is slowing down your job in spark3. In spark2, it was using hive serdes(orc/parquet) for read and write. In spark3, spark uses its own native serdes. For large no of partitions this metatstore action becomes slow. You can set the following and then see the difference.

```
spark.sql.hive.convertMetastoreOrc=false
spark.sql.hive.convertMetastoreParquet=false
```

Comment: Thanks for the ANSWER, very effective, but the spark3 official website indicates that performance is better with spark.sql.hive.convertMetastoreParquet=true, why is this able, is it because my hive metastoreserver memory is too small, or the mysql that stores the metadata Response is too slow?

Comment: I agree on the performance caveat that you mentioned. The flag that I asked to set is a workaround to let the job complete. Proper solution is to have better partitioning strategy.

Comment: On your second point, it is not because of metastore. When making a call to metastore spark uses thrift protocol. In this spark will ask for all the metadata of the partitions at once to reduce the roundtrip, but the downside of this is that it has to wait for all the data to be collected and buffered at once. With large no of partitions (and depending on the metadata of files) it can take a considerable amount of time. In some cases (say you have more than 5L partitions) it might throw timeout. In hive 4.0 there is a patch to get the partitions in batches. But spark still uses hive 2.3.9.

Comment: Oh! You are my god! I found that hivemetastore mysqlServer's slow logs and those queries with sql are running slow and your description matches my findings very well.